# How to log multiple Jupyter Notebooks to the same log file when executed in batch?

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

I am executing multiple Jupyter Notebook programatically one after the other following the [documentation here](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html). Short code detail below.

I am able to create a log file for each individual notebook and for the "master" notebook from which I am executing the others. **How can I have all the notebooks log to the same file?**

Many thanks in advance!

*Functions to read and execute the Jupyter notebooks:*

```
def read_in_notebook(notebook_fp):
    with open(notebook_fp) as f:
        nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
    return nb

def execute_notebook(notebook_filename,timeout=60000, allow_errors=False):

    nb = read_in_notebook(notebook_filename)
    ep = ExecutePreprocessor(allow_errors = allow_errors, timeout=timeout, 
                            kernel_name='python3')
    try:
        logging.info('We are loading {0}.'.format(notebook_filename))
        out = ep.preprocess(nb, {})
    except CellExecutionError as error:
        logging.warning('We have run into {0} in file {1}.'.format(error, 
                       notebook_filename))
    finally:
        nbformat.write(nb, open(notebook_filename, mode='w'))
```

*Loop through the Jupyter Notebooks and execute one after the other:*

```
for file in files_:
     execute_notebook(file)
```